# Android Java ArrayList Iterator.next() or List.get() return always the same Object

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My ArrayList iterator or the get() function of the List (with several indexes) always return the last element of the list. I am very new to Java and cannot understand why is there no begin() and end() for the iterator like in C++. How can I jump to ther first element?
If I while() with the iterator through the list with hasNext() and next() and Log() this to the console, there are 20 times the same object if the list have a size of 20.

Object:

```
public class JokeObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1703441755022251852L;
    public int num;
    public int jokeid;
    public String joke;
    public int votes;
}
```

Object holder class:

```
public class JokeHolder {

    private ArrayList <JokeObject> jokeList;
    private Iterator<JokeObject> jokeIt;
    private JokeObject lastJokeObj;

    public JokeHolder() {
        jokeList = new ArrayList<JokeObject>();
        jokeIt = jokeList.iterator();
        lastJokeObj = null;
    }

    public void AddJoke(JokeObject obj) {
        this.jokeList.add(obj);
    }

    public JokeObject GetNextJoke() {
        if (jokeIt.hasNext()) {
            lastJokeObj = jokeIt.next();
            return lastJokeObj;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public int GetHolderSize() {
        return (jokeList.size());
    }

    public void SetList(ArrayList<JokeObject> aList) {
        jokeList.clear();
        jokeList.addAll(aList);
        this.jokeIt = this.jokeList.iterator();
    }

    public void SetLastObj(JokeObject obj) {
        this.lastJokeObj = obj;     
    }

    public ArrayList<JokeObject> GetList() {
        return jokeList;
    }

    public JokeObject GetLastObject() {
        return lastJokeObj;
    }
}
```

In activity A:

```
jokes.AddJoke(obj);
```

In activity B:

```
obj = myJokes.GetNextJoke();
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you add the Jokes to the JokeHolder class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the iterator will "refresh" when you add an item to the list.  Maybe this will work better.  Store an index of what joke you're and get the jokes like this:

```
public JokeObject GetNextJoke() {
    if (if index < jokeList.size()) {
        lastJokeObj = jokeList.get(i);
        index++;
        return lastJokeObj;
    }

    return null;
}
```